# Arduino IDE v 2.2.1 log file not limited in size (on Ubuntu 23.04)

Tags: arduino-ide, ubuntu

I was learning/building with a new Arduino Nano ESP32 yesterday and left the Arduino IDE running overnight on Ubuntu 23.04 and it used all the space on my hard drive to write log files which broke my system till I booted in with a pen drive and removed some files to make space to then boot normally and find out what the problem was.

How can I limit the size of these log files, or even disable them?

Comment: I have been having the same issue. I think it might have something to do with the serial monitor being open, but I haven't found a fix yet.

Comment: Well, you could do it at the Unix level if you can't restrict it otherwise say using a volume quota, a script or other trick.